# Can i eliminate down button on <datalist> tag?

Tags: html, attr

`<datalist>` is an HTML5 tag which is use in order to order elements and choose them. when i use it with `<input>`, it gives me [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist).

[image]

i dont want to see list items like that before i typed it on, so can i  eliminate this down button on it. is there an attribute for this?

**ALSO** can i use it other tags than `<input>`

***NO*** *is not an answer for this question!*

Answer (score 5):

To remove the down arrow, try using the following in your CSS:

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/5UYdy/

Comment: it killed the real function of the tag

Comment: @user3301042 double click reveals all options, typing a letter brings suggestions, works here

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no selector which does it.

**BUT!**
You can add `required` attribute to the `<input>` tag. Then, we can access this input by CSS3 tags:

- `input:valid` - when input has content
- `input:invalid` - when input is blank

Adding following style:

```
input:invalid::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```

will show the list only when the input is not empty.

The following JSFiddle shows that in action, hope it helps:
http://jsfiddle.net/5UYdy/2/

The only disadvantage is that the input is required.

And no, you can't use it with other elements, according to *W3Schools*

> The  tag specifies a list of pre-defined options for an  element.

Answer (score 1):

This will remove history of an input box but...,

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

---

> but I think there is no way to remove `<datalist>`

---

Answer (score 0):

your best bet is this:

```css
 input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
     opacity: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-field__control">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    list="currency"
                    id="currency"
                  />
                  <datalist id="currency">
                    <option>Dollars</option>
                    <option>Pounds</option>
                    <option>Naira</option>
                    <option>Peso</option>
                  </datalist>
                </div>
```